# Laravel pagination at leftjoin

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, left-join

I want to create leftjoin with pagination on laravel.
how to create pagination with leftjoin ?

Here my code :

```
$news = News::leftJoin('categories','news.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
        ->select('news.*' ,'categories.category')
        ->get()->sortByDesc('created_at');
```

Previously, i use `$news = News::paginate(10);` and its works, but it without leftjoin.

and here my html code to create pagination

```
{{$news->links('vendor.pagination.pagination')}}
```

Comment: sortByDesc() must be before get()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The paginate function should be done on the Query Builder object, not on the collection returned by `get()`.

```
$news = News::leftJoin('categories','news.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
        ->select('news.*' ,'categories.category')
        ->paginate(10);
```

The same goes for sorting.  When you call `get()->sortByDesc()`, you are getting a Collection then sorting the collection through PHP.  Normally, you would want to use `orderBy()` in the query builder to sort through SQL.

```
$news = News::leftJoin('categories','news.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
        ->select('news.*' ,'categories.category')
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
        ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: thank you
but it getting error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::links()` now. how to show pagination at my view ? i've been use this code `{{$news->links()}}`

Comment: You're missing something here, it's saying `$news` is still a query builder object instead of a paginator object.

Answer (score 0):

Use Eloquent: Relationships

For example:

News.php model

```
class News extends Model
    {
        protected $primaryKey = 'id';

        function withCategories() {
       return $this->hasOne('App\Categories', 'id', 'category_id');
    }

    public function list(){
         News::with('withCategories')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->paginate(10);
    }
}
```

in news.blade.php (example)

```
<table>
<tbody>
@foreach ($news as $news)
<tr>
<th>{{ $news->id }}</th>
<td>{{ $news->title }}</td>
<td>{{ $news->withCategories->title }}</td> <!-- Category name-->
</tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```